# Linking my NSIS script file into Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, scripting, nsis

In my Jenkins build i want it to read my `NSIS` script file. This is how it looks.

`installer.exe/D=C:\Program Files(x86)\NSIS`

But Jenkins keep failing to build correctly from this. Anybody who can help me?

Comment: do you have a missing space between `.exe` and `/D=...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new batch command with following:

path_to_NSIS_folder>\makensis.exe path_to_your_nsi_file

makensis.exe is a NSIS compiler and all it needs is path to the script file (.nsi).

When run the script is compiled and (if no errors) reslting setup.exe is created (the output can se set in .nsi file).

This code was given to me by another user and works perfectly although I didn't structure this question correctly. But this is the answer.